# How do I pass multiple clocking blocks with different polariy from an system verilog interface?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have an system verilog interface

```
interface XZY(input clk, input reset, input a, output b);
    clocking cb @(posedge clk);
        input a;
        output b;
    endclocking: cb

   modport master(clocking cb, input reset);


endinterface: XYZ
```

I am passing the interface as `virtual interface` to my driver.

The driver is using the `moport`(`master`).

Now I need to access both the `posedge` and the `negedge` of the clock in my driver.

I can easily access the `posedge` by `@cb`.

How do I access the `negedge`?

Do i need to create another `modport`/`clocking block` for the `negedge` and pass it separately to the driver?

Comment: You can just pass 'clk' through modport in this case and use its edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a clocking block for both positive and negative edge clocks. You can have both clocking blocks listed in your modport. You don't need a modport when in your driver/monitor.

If you want to dynamically choose the polarity with the same clocking block then see my answer here: [Changing clocking block clock polarity on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56949594/1959732). This works for a polarity mode switch; I would not recommend it if both edges are needed in the same transaction.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to use a clocking block as the only mechanism for accessing signals in your interface, then you'll have to create another clocking block. I normally don't use modports in verification interfaces, but you would have to add the clocking bock to your existing modport or add another one.